# How to wait until SharePoint Site and Document Library have been created before moving to next steps in Power Automate flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-teams

I have the following Power Automate Flow steps set up:

1. Create a team ([connector docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/#create-a-team))
   which returns the team's `newTeamId`
2. Create a channel ([connector docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/#create-a-channel-(preview)))
   which returns the channel's `description`, `displayName` and `id`
3. Get a team ([connector docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/#get-a-team-(preview)))
   which returns a `GetTeamResponse` [connector docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/#getteamresponse)
4. Send an HTTP request to SharePoint ([connector docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint))
   which is a `POST` request to create a Document Library
5. Create file ([connector docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#create-file))
   which is supposed to create a file in the new Document Library and returns a `SPBlobMetadataResponse` ([connector docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#spblobmetadataresponse))

Currently I am adding a `Delay` action of 2 minutes between steps `3-4` and `4-5`, so that I can ensure the resource it relies upon is ready, ie:

- The SharePoint site associated with the newly created Team is ready to create a Document Library in it
- The newly created Document Library is ready for a file to be created in it

**Desired Behaviour**

Rather than use `Delay`, I would like to programmatically check if the resources are ready to be interacted with.

**Current Behaviour**

Using `Delay` is not producing consistent results.

Sometime steps `4` and `5` take place after the delay, and sometimes I get `403` errors which seem to be related to the resource not being ready to be interacted with.

**Question**

How can I achieve the following functionality:

- Wait until the SharePoint site is fully provisioned and ready to be interacted with before moving to next step
- Wait until the Document Library is fully provisioned and ready to be interacted with before moving to next step

**Research:**

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oPFlXFczAU) suggests an approach using `Get lists` ([connector docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-lists)) but it seems to involve a single conditional check of whether a `403` or `404` is returned which then proceeds based on that check (rather than *waiting* until the relevant resource is ready).